# Clear all data after copying it but leaving all functions and formulas

Tags: vba, copy, paste

I'd like to either clear the sheet after copying the content of the cells but without deleting the Excel functions, or cut everything from the current region but again, leaving functions in columns H and I intact.

The code is as follows and works well but I don't know how to clear the sheet and leave the functions intact. The functions are in columns H and I

> ```
> Sub archive_old_data()
> ```

```
'copy Admissions sheet into Archive sheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

MsgBox "Please make sure you've reviewed all patients before archiving data."

Worksheets("Admissions").Activate
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
Worksheets("Archive").Activate
Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
Worksheets("Admissions").Activate




End Sub
```

I would appreciate some help.

I don't have to copy currentregion, I need whatever is in cells A2:E2, but the problem is that next time I copy it might be  A2:E9, another time A11:E11

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove all number-values from a range you can use:

```
    Range("A1:D4").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).ClearContents
```

To clear both text and numbers (but not formulas) use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 3)`.

If you are not sure of the specific range then you might apply this to entire columns, or `Cells` for the entire sheet.

---

If there is the possibility that there won't be any values to delete then you should include some error-handling, otherwise the error 'No cells were found' appears.